# unicorn + systemd: losing logging after unicorn upgrade

Tags: fedora, systemd, process-management

I'm deploying unicorn with systemd for the first time (actually, this is the first time I'm using systemd at all), and I'm using unicorn's ["zero-downtime upgrade" trick](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/examples/init.sh), or basically:

- Send `USR2` to the master process
- This causes a new master & workers to spawn, the old pidfile to be renamed, and the new pidfile to reflect the new master's PID
- Send QUIT to the old master
- This causes the old workers to handle their current request and exit, and the old master to die

This is all working great, except for one thing: systemd's log capturing (for `systemctl status`) doesn't see the new process's output. I'm guessing this is because it wasn't involved in the handoff process or something?

systemd *is* seeing the new master's PID and tracking it correctly.

If I set `preload_app = false` in unicorn's config and just HUP the master (which does not change the master's PID), everything is fine -- but that doesn't take care of the case where I actually want to upgrade unicorn.

In case it matters, I'm not having unicorn daemonize, and have `Type=simple` in my unit config file.

Is there any way to get systemd to attach itself to the new master's log output?